# Improve loop over nested properties - javascript

Tags: javascript, lodash

Trying to filter students according to a nested property value.
Basically each student object has property of type array : `studentSuperSubject`
which in turn has array as a property as well : `studentSubSubjectOrSkill`
`subjects` is array of objects in the following form:
`{superSubject: "some super subject name", subSubject: "some sub subject name"}`.
each `subSubject` inside `studentSubSubjectOrSkill` has the property `studentSubSubjectScore` which is the one I'm looking for.
I want to loop over the students array for each subject in `subjects` and create and object i then store to another array  - `grades=[]`

I manage to get it done with what looks like a Hugh bawl of spaghetti code:

```
  for (let subject of subjects) {
    var grades = [];
    this.data.students.filter(student => {
      let name = student.studentName;

      // loop over each student > superSubject > subSubject
      for (let superSubject of student.studentSuperSubject) {
        if (superSubject.superSubjectName === subject.superSubject) {
          superSubject.studentSubSubjectOrSkill.filter(sub => {
            if (sub.subSubjectName === subject.subSubject) {
              grades.push({
                name: name,
                pass: sub.studentSubSubjectScore > 58
              });
              return;
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });
    subject["grades"] = grades;
  }
```

Any idea how can I improve that to make life easier for the future developers which are going to use this code? 
as a side note, lodash is available in this project
thanks.

Comment: You already use `filter` on the students, I would use it for the inner for loop as well. And you can replace the outer for loop with `map`

Answer (score 0):

1/ You have improper use of filter that should be used when you want to return subset of the array, you should use map when you want to execute an action for each element of the array

2/ for... of ... is for iterating over the values, for... in... over the properties

3/ I think it is more readable like this:

```
for (let subject of subjects) {
    var grades = [];

    this.data.students.map(student => {
      let name = student.studentName;

      student.studentSuperSubject
          .filter(superSubject => superSubject.superSubjectName === subject.superSubject)
          .map(superSubject=> {                     
              superSubject.studentSubSubjectOrSkill
                  .filter(sub => sub.subSubjectName === subject.subSubject)
                  .map(sub=>{
                      grades.push({
                          name: name,
                          pass: sub.studentSubSubjectScore > 58
                      });
                  });
          });
      });

   subject["grades"] = grades;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For readability, I would check one thing at a time and add some comments.

```
// Iterates for all subjects.
subjects.forEach(subject => {
    // Subject grades.
    subject.grades = [];

    // Iterates for all the students.
    students.forEach(student => {
        // Finds and validates the student super subject.
        var studentSuperSubject = student.studentSuperSubject.find(superSubject => superSubject.superSubjectName === subject.superSubject);
        if (!studentSuperSubject) return;

        // Finds and validates the student sub subject.
        var studentSubSubject = studentSuperSubject.studentSubSubjectOrSkill.find(subSubject => subSubject.subSubjectName == subject.subSubject);
        if (!studentSubSubject) return;

        // Saves the student grade.
        subject.grades.push({
            name: student.studentName,
            pass: studentSubSubject.studentSubSubjectScore > 58
        });
    });
});
```